# Rank of symmetric matrix $X^T D X$

Tags: matrices

Let $X$ be a real $(n \times p)$ matrix, and $D$ be a diagonal $(n \times n)$ matrix with all $d_{ii} > 0$.

What can we say about the rank of the symmetric matrix $X^TDX$?

At the moment I have that $\text{rank}(X^TDX) \leq \min(\text{rank}(X^T), \text{rank}(DX)) = \min(\text{rank}(X), \text{rank}(X)) = \text{rank}(X)$

Are there any conditions under which the inequality would become an equality?

Answer (score 1):

Yes they can be equal. Assume $n<p$ and rows of $X$ are orthonormal. Then $X$ has a rank $n.$ In this case $X^TDX$ will be of rank $n$ too since $d_{ii}>0$ (imagine singular value decomposition). So in this case we have $$\text{rank}(X^TDX) = \text{rank}(X)$$

Answer (score 0):

One condition in the case of $n=p$, where it becomes an equality, would be $X = I$.